# python shutil.move [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '116431103.jpg'

Tags: python, move, shutil, ends-with

hello guys i try to move all pictures to the folder and i getting an error can you please help me, i have been 25hours looking for the solution on internet  Without success, please see the screen

[image]

---

```
import shutil
import os


class DFO_engine:
    def __init__(self):
        desk_source = open("desk_source.txt", "r")
        direct_files = open("Direction_files.txt", "r")
        link = direct_files.readlines()
        desktop = os.listdir(desk_source.readline())
        pictures_folder = link[0]
        for files in desktop:
            if files.endswith(".jpg"):
                print(files)
                shutil.move(files, pictures_folder)

    desk_source.close()
    direct_files.close()


action = DFO_engine()
```

Comment: `shutil.move(desktop + r'\' + files, pictures_folder)`

Comment: You need to prepend the desktop path

Comment: @OlvinRoght At the end of the code I see an error, as String
https://i.ibb.co/Y7mxYZG/ee.png

Comment: @soufiane use `'\\'`

Comment: @OlvinRoght 
shutil.move(desktop + r'\\' + files, pictures_folder)

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
??

Comment: @jbflow can you please write code to me !!

Comment: change desktop to desk_source.readline()
```shutil.move(desk_source.readline() + r'\\' + files, pictures_folder)```

Comment: For the purposes of best practice you should really be using a ```with``` statement when your opening files.

Comment: @jbflow stile i have same problem this is the result  
https://i.ibb.co/dPpztrr/22222222re.png
https://i.ibb.co/Jj0DBsc/ss1111pture.png

Comment: just use ```path = os.path.join(desk_source.readline(), files)```, then you should be able to just do: ```shutil.move(path, pictures_folder```At this point can I also ask why you've got your paths held externally in text files, it seems unnecessary

Comment: You might still have to deal with the escape characters. Using a raw string literal (r'') would normally do that, but you still can't end with a backslash. This is why I'm asking about the path in the external files as this is adding unnecessary complications.

Comment: @jbflow thank you so much, it's working now 100% thank you